# Finding the probability of an anomalous hourly trading bar on the NDX/NASDAQ

Tags: probability

The NDX Futures is an ETF that's traded nearly round the clock. On an hourly basis, it looks like this:

[image]

Each bar drawn has a starting price for the hour (open price), a high price, a low price, and an ending price (close).  Open price is the left "notch" on the bar, and closing price is the right "notch" on the bar. On the above chart, bars where the close price is higher than the open price, the bar is green; where the close price is lower, the bar is red.

The bars can vary in range from a few pennies to a few hundred dollars. Typically the open price of a bar is within 1 to 3 dollars/points of the close price of the previous bar.

Recently, a bar formed that was grey in color.  I have never seen this in years examining these graphs.  In order for it to form, the open price has to be identical to the close price to the penny:

[image]

To calculate a rough probability of that grey bar forming, is it rational to approach it as:

1. the probability of any open price is about 1 in ~300 (figure 3-point possible deviation from prior close, and up to 99 cents fractionation for each point, rounded up)
2. the probability of any close price is about 1 in ~40,000 (figure 400 possible points deviation from the open, with again up to 99 cent fraction for each point, rounded up).
3. (1/300) * (1/40,000) = 1 in 70 million chance?

Bearing in mind, the close price has to form at that exact tick before the bar closes (I wonder if this, too, impacts the probability).

Thanks!

Comment: Essentially you want to calculate the probability that the ending price is the same as the opening price? Under your model this is just 1/40,000. Whether your model is rational is another question. Usually, one would use a lognormal distribution to model the ending price given the opening price and then you would have to calculate the probability that this lognormal random variable is very close to 0.

Comment: Exactly...  do you think the log-normal would yield a way lower probability or higher?  Or that 1/40,000 is rational?  Would 1/(average bar length) yield something close to a log-normal?  Given that any bar length under 400 can form almost at any time ("Random Walk Theory"), I thought that was relatively reasonable.  I've never calc'd a log-normal, nor is statistics in my academic purview...

Comment: Again this really depends on the parameter of the chosen log normal distribution. In practice one would estimate these using data from the past. I'm afraid I cannot give real answer on whether 1/40,000 is a good estimation.

Comment: What if we assume there is equal probability in any length bar forming, where the past does not at dictate the next bar's length?  Btw, I realized there's only 4 possibilities per point since they're in 25-cent increments.  Figuring max bar length of 400, that's max possibilities of 1/(400+ 4(400)) or 1/2000.  Then 3 possibilities on the open, so 1/(3 + 3(4)) or 1/15.  So chances of picking the same open and close value is 1/15 * 1/2000, or 1/30,000. ...?